# Use of pattern $match $in in aggregate function of Mongo PHP Library

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using Mongo PHP Library in my code: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/

I am trying to send following query to MongoDB using aggregate function in Mongo PHP Library:

> Blockquote

```
db.customers.aggregate(
{$match: {Country: "India", Email: {$in: [/.*@gmail.com*/,/.*@hotmail.com*/] } } },
{$group : {_id : {Email: "Email"}, "count" : {$sum : 1} } },
{$sort : {"count" : -1} }
)
```

This query works fine on MongoDB Server. But in PHP code it isn't working.

> Blockquote

```
$query = array(
['$match' => ['Country' => "India", 
              'Email' => ['$in' => ['/.*@gmail.com*/','/.*@hotmail.com*/']]
             ]
],
['$group' => ['_id' => ['Email' => '$Email']
              'count' => ['$sum' => 1]
             ]
],
['$sort' => ['count' => -1]]
);
$cursor = $this->customers->aggregate($query);
```

$in array is not working with wildcard pattern as above. It doesn't show any error or result. But it works with exact email. How can i mention the pattern in $in array under $match

Please suggest how can i submit the wildcard pattern in Mongo PHP library.

Comment: Edit: ['_id' => ['Email' => '$Email'],

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$query = array(
array('$match' => array('Country' => "India",'Email' => 
    array('$in' => array('/.*@gmail.com*/','/.*@hotmail.com*/'))
)),

array('$group' =>  array('_id' =>  array('Email' => '$Email')
              'count' =>  array('$sum' => 1)
             )
),
 array('$sort' =>  array('count' => -1))
);
```